# Using Scanner to check if a given input can be added to a Linked List assigned to a given type

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, java.util.scanner

So, I'm tinkering around with Java's Linked List class; and after implementing my own variant, I'm trying to replicate the "Josephus Problem" with my own implementation. Is there a possible way to use  `java.util.Scanner`  to check if a given user input can be added to a Linked List of a given type?

Example:

```
MyLinkedList<Integer> list = new MyLinkedList<>();
java.util.Scanner stdin = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

//If user input's is of the linked list's parametrized type 
//(i.e. Integer, Double, String, etc)
list.add(stdin.(nextType));
//repeat for the 8 primitive type's wrapper classes and then for String and 
//for custom Objects
```

Where one class has the constructor and a given add method, and another class calls upon the constructor, where the constructor then prompts the user to enter values of the list's type (Integer, Double, etc.) until the user enters a command to stop inputting new data items.

1) Does what I ask make sense?

2) Is there a way to do this? If not, could someone point me in the right direction for this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you read the Scanner javadoc? You would get an instant response.

Comment: I didn't think of that. Thank you!

Comment: When you are talking of the primitive types, there will be ambiguity as a float and double can be the same (outside of precision) and long/integer will differ in long's capacity beyond MAX_INT, and String can be a Character if length is 1.  So your first tasks may be to just read the data and figure out what you have.  Commons Lang3 has nice helpers like  NumberUtils to check if parseable.

Comment: @AlexC My main concern would be if I can determine the difference between Integer and Double versus String and Character, as that's where I'm having the most problems. When I thought I had an Idea for this, because of the MyLinkedList class being generic, generifying the scanner would lead to type erasure, this making the code I wrote useless.

Comment: Difference between integer and double is '.' and a character is a string of length 1.  That's a start at least, other than that there is no way to know from string, so "5" can be an int but can also be a double but you would expect a double to be "5.0".  NumberUtils.isParsable (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html)  can check for a number, then look for a period to make sure it's a double.